# Hugo - Taking a video title and turning it into a URL

Tags: html, regex, url, hugo

I'm working with Hugo and have a use case where there are a lot of various video titles that all follow roughly the same considerations:

- remove all underscores and replace with dashes
- remove all dashes with spaces on either side and replace with a dash with no spaces
- remove all special characters (? and !) and replace with nothing
- remove all periods and replace with dashes
- remove all remaining spaces and replace with dashes
- everything lowercase

So far I have the following code written out, and I'm trying to figure out how to streamline it.

```
                          {{ $step1_title := replace .title "_" " " }}
                          {{ $step2_title := replace $step1_title " - " "-" }}
                          {{ $step3_title := replace $step2_title "?" "" }}
                          {{ $step4_title := replace $step3_title "." "-" }}
                          {{ $step5_title := replace $step4_title " " "-" | lower }}
                          {{ $step5_title }}
```

It seems like a lot of steps, and doesn't account for both ? and !. I'm assuming `replaceRE` would be more appropriate for that step, yet it won't recognize those characters when defined with `[?]|[!]`. Any pointers for making the above more efficient would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, you've failed step #1 per your first bullet point requirement.

Comment: Are `?` and `!` the only special characters not allowed in video titles?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your first comment as that's immediately what is taken care of by the first step of my code. It replaces underscores with spaces which later are converted to dashes. Correct, only those two (at least those are the only two encountered with the set of data). If there's a general selector for special characters that would also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For others looking for an answer - Hugo does actually have a built-in function called `urlize` that does exactly this!

https://gohugo.io/functions/urlize/

For the curious, there is an opposite function that "humanizes" the string and returns it with separators removed and the first letter capitalized:

https://gohugo.io/functions/humanize/